# Docker - Set up multiple projects no matter the framework(on php)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Well, this is a question that has been around but the fact is, many people uses a different approach and because of that i feel kinda lost on how to configure things.

- Some say that the .yml should be in each project folder along with
  the dockerfile and it also makes sense because this way you will have
  everything organized, but everytime i have to load my projects i have to docker-compose up on each folder?!?
- Others say, you should have a .yml file in the root of your projects folder with all of the configurations of each project and then a dockerfile per project folder, so:

projects folder

docker-compose.yml

-> projects A folder (dockerfile)

-> projects B folder (dockerfile)

At the end, it´s up to you which type of configuration you want, but i must say that doing docker-compose up just once and have all your projects up and running is very practical and i **just can´t understand how to configure this**, and i was hopping someone could walk me through the path of light!. It doens´t matter the frameworks what i need is to work with php, mysql and nginx or apache. Below is a peace of code i found and have been trying to work with but i also found [this](https://dev.to/aschmelyun/the-beauty-of-docker-for-local-laravel-development-13c0) but it´s giving me an error about the belogs_to not being an array:

```
version: '3'
services:
  project1:
    build:
      context: /project1 #automatically finds Dockerfile
    container_name: project1
    ports:
      – 8081:80
    volumes:
      – .:/app/project
   links:
      – mysql
  project2:
    build:
      context: /project2 #automatically finds Dockerfile
    container_name: project2
    ports:
      – 8082:80
    volumes:
      – .:/app/project
   links:
      – mysql
  ...
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      – 13306:3306
    volumes:
      - /data:var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?  Are you getting an error message with that `docker-compose.yml` file?  (You don't need to manually specify `container_name:`, `links:` don't do anything, and overwriting your images' code with `volumes:` can lead to problems you have trouble reproducing; you should, however, `depends_on: [mysql]`; and it's common to have a distinct database per project.  But overall it looks like it should work.)

Comment: Hi David, first of all, thanks for answering, the thing is, i´m new to docker and i´m trying to understand how everything ties. Would it be possible for you to show me some code?. Are you saying that this peace of code is not giving a database per project?. thanks

Comment: Every container is sharing the same `mysql` container at the end of your file.  Many of the [official Docker sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/#sample-applications) are Compose-based.

Comment: Hi Dave, i´ve found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtT32MW2j9c .... at minute 4:36 where it puts the image, should i point to my project? i mean my project A folder and inside of it add the dockerfile?